# xpath: nested nodes with same name

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Is it possible to write Xpath exression to find following nodes:

```
a/b/c
a/b/b/c
a/b/b/b/c
a/b/b/b/.../b/.../b/c
```

etc.

but not

```
a/b/b/e/b/c
```

?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You mean something similar to the regular expression `ab+c` ?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with xpath alone. Your requirement seems to suggest that the final result shouldn't contain `e`, in that case you should transform your xml using xslt to remove `e` and you may run xpath on it.

Comment: @ceving exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following input:

```
<root>
    <a><b><c>1</c></b></a>
    <a><b><b><c>2</c></b></b></a>
    <a><b><b><b><c>3</c></b></b></b></a>
    <a><b><b><e><b><c>4</c></b></e></b></b></a>
    <a><b><b><e><b><b><c>5</c></b></b></e></b></b></a>
</root>
```

You can try the following expression:

```
//a[deep-equal(distinct-values(descendant::*[position()<last()]/name()), ('b'))]//c
```

How it works:

For any `a` the names of all but the last descendant are calculated and it is checked if the distinct list of that names matches the list containing just `b`. And for such an `a` the descendant `c` is one you want to select.

I tested it with the 2010 version of XMLSpy, which returns the `c` elements containing 1, 2 and 3. I think more modern tools will also work. But you need at least XPath 2.0 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not totally clear, but you can try to use below expression:

```
//a[.//b and not(.//e)]//c[not(.//*)]
```

This should allow to match `c`that has no own child and is descendant of `a`, that has `b` descendant, but not `e`

*UPDATE*

You can try

```
//a[count(.//b)=count(.//*)-count(.//c)]//c[not(.//*)]
```

or

```
//a[not(.//*[not(self::b)]//c)]//c[not(.//*)]
```

Comment: I want that only tags with name b are located   between a and c

Comment: Check updated answer and let le know if issue still persist